# how to achieve the above requirement in sql

Tags: sql-server

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.KeyValuePairs( @inputStr VARCHAR(MAX)) 
    RETURNS @OutTable TABLE 
       (KeyName VARCHAR(MAX), KeyValue VARCHAR(MAX))

    AS
    BEGIN

       DECLARE @separator CHAR(1), @keyValueSeperator CHAR(1)
       SET @separator = ','
       SET @keyValueSeperator = ':'

       DECLARE @separator_position INT , @keyValueSeperatorPosition INT
       DECLARE @match VARCHAR(MAX) 

       SET @inputStr = @inputStr + @separator

       WHILE PATINDEX('%' + @separator + '%' , @inputStr) <> 0 
        BEGIN
         SELECT @separator_position =  PATINDEX('%' + @separator + '%' , @inputStr)
         SELECT @match = LEFT(@inputStr, @separator_position - 1)
         IF @match <> '' 
                BEGIN
            SELECT @keyValueSeperatorPosition = PATINDEX('%' + @keyValueSeperator + '%' , @match)
            IF @keyValueSeperatorPosition <> -1 
              BEGIN
                     INSERT @OutTable
                             VALUES (LEFT(@match,@keyValueSeperatorPosition -1),
                             RIGHT(@match,LEN(@match) - @keyValueSeperatorPosition))
             END
                 END        
        SELECT @inputStr = STUFF(@inputStr, 1, @separator_position, '')
       END

       RETURN
END
GO
```

when input is '1:10,2:20'
This gives the output as  string parse

```
 KeyName   KeyValue
  1          10
  2          20
```

I need additional logic on top of it: I will send 
'Stadium','1:10,2:20' as input to a function then 
output should be

```
StadiumA         StadiumB
  10                  20
```

i.e: in 1:10,2:20' key 1 refers to A AND append 'Stadium' to it .
key 2 refers to B and  append 'Stadium' to it an so on continues

I have tried joining with below

```sql
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ParseDeviceTopology](@Type NVARCHAR(255),@Value NVARCHAR(MAX))
    RETURNS @Parsed TABLE (Topology NVARCHAR(50),Value NVARCHAR(50))
    AS
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @Parsed(Topology,Value)
        SELECT @Type  + m.Topology + 'Version' AS Topology,p.[1] AS [Value]
        FROM (
            SELECT j.[key] AS [ID],i.[key],i.value
            FROM OPENJSON('["' + REPLACE(@Value,',','","') + '"]') j
           -- CROSS APPLY OPENJSON('[' + REPLACE(j.[value],':',',') + ']') i
           CROSS APPLY OPENJSON('["' + REPLACE(j.[value],':','","') + '"]') i
        ) a
        PIVOT(MAX(a.value) FOR a.[key] IN ([0],[1])) p
        INNER JOIN ( VALUES`   ` INNER JOIN ( VALUES
            (2,'B')
            ,(1,'A')
            ,(3,'C')
        )` `m(ID, Topology) ON m.ID = p.[0];
```

But I was getting the output as required in my local machine 2016 SQL but this logic uses OPENJSON which is incompatible in SQL 2014 where I need to deploy. Please help me out

Comment: I think you are on the right path but convert it to xml rather than json. I think that's been around for longer.

Comment: 1:10,2:20 & 'Stadium','1:10,2:20' are fixed format?

Comment: In order to dynamically name columns you need to use dynamic sql. You are using a function here and you can't use dynamic sql in a function. As a side note, you have a multi-statement table valued function here which is a performance timebomb. They are notoriously bad for performance, even worse than scalar functions.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly wouldn't do this in SQL, instead, parse the key value pairs into an object in your external code.

If you absolutely have to do this in SQL I would suggest looking at using a CLR string splitter function as detailed here https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

In your case you would need an initial pass to split by comma to return a single column of tabular data, then a pass of that column to split by the semi colon.